# Selenium random Numbers need to enter in field box

Tags: java, arrays, selenium, collections

Tried for random numbers by using for loop with count.
I have a field box in that every time it should take random numbers 
example: first I enter 1.8$ and run it will accept this number. 
after I close the browser and re-run the program it should take the value by its own number but not the previous number mainly it should take decimal values which is greater than 1 & ex: 1.1,1.23 like these numbers only it accepts.

Comment: what you have done so far?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. In order to receive assistance with the code please provide [mcve]

Comment: Random r= new Random , for(double i=0;j<10<j++){ driver.findelement(by.id("text box").sendkeys(""+j); this is how i tried but when i enter it taking value after i close the browser and rerun it is taking same as before value so how could the system will pick up random numbers

Comment: @Nikolay ... Random r = new Random(); for(j=0.87;j<9.8;j++){ driver.findelement(by.id("text box").sendkeys(""+j); i tried by this when i run it took 0.87 first time and i close the browser again it takes same value can you let me know how to generate ranodm value by system every time i run the code

Comment: Edit your attempts into the question (and format it as code), not in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

**use this method :**

```
public float getDecimalRandomNumber(){
        // create instance of Random class
        Random rand = new Random();
        // Generate and return Random number with decimal
        return rand.nextFloat();
    }
```

**call it in sendKeys function**

```
driver.findelement(by.id("text box").sendkeys(""+getDecimalRandomNumber());
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned that the value should not be the previous one, in that case, you should not use any random number. There are chances you will get the same random number. So instead of doing that, you should have to store the state of your variable in a static variable so all the object instances can access the variable and each time increase that number by `.1` or by any suitable number. You will not be worrying about the duplication of value.

```
 public class Sample{
        private static float inputNumber= 1.1f;

        public static float getInputNumber() {
            return inputNumber+ 0.1f;
        }
    }
```